# enqueue script won't work (enqueue style does work)

Tags: javascript

To include a CSS file and a JS file I added to `functions.php`:

```
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}

function my_theme_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'behavior', get_script_directory_uri() . '/behavior.js', array(), null, true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_style', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_script', 'my_theme_enqueue_scripts' );
```

After doing so, I saved and closed the editor, went back to the same directory of functions.php (this is the child theme's directory), ad created a new file, `behavior.js`.

In `behavior.js`, I added, just for testing:

```
alert('Hi');
```

I saved, went back to my site, and did full refresh, but no alert appears. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the wrong hook. `wp_enqueue_scripts` is the correct hook for both:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_scripts' );
```

But since they're the same hook you can just enqueue both files in the same callback:

```
function my_theme_enqueue_assets() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_parent_theme_file_uri( 'style.css' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'behavior', get_theme_file_uri( 'behavior.js' ), array(), null, true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_assets' );
```

I've also used the newer `get_parent_theme_file_uri()` and `get_theme_file_uri()` functions to get the file URLs. `get_parent_theme_file_uri()` will get the URI for the given file inside the parent theme only, while `get_theme_file_uri()` will get the file from the current theme, and if it's a child theme it will fall back to the parent theme if the file doesn't exist in the child theme.

Note that these still need the path to the file inside the theme if they're in a folder, eg. `get_theme_file_uri( 'path/to/file.js' );`

Comment: This made my site show WSOD...

Comment: Well not WSOD. CTRL+U shows some little bit HTML, but the CSS isn't loaded at all. I just see a white blank page. No HTML by my page builder (Elementor) is loaded so it seems adding a JS make my page builder not to load.

Comment: `get_script_directory_uri()` isn't a function, you're getting an error because `my_theme_enqueue_scripts` is correctly hooked, but contains this error.

Comment: So if in my case `get_script_directory_uri()` is not a function that is declared anywhere, what should replace it? Also, I'm using a child theme, maybe another function needed instead this one?

Comment: When I had only a style.css reference with `get_script_directory_uri()` the site worked fine.

Comment: Your style function works because `wp_enqueue_style` is using `get_template_directory_uri`, and it wasn't broken before because `my_theme_enqueue_scripts()` wasn't running at all. I'd didn't twig that you were in a child theme, so I'll update my answer.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a better solution.

Comment: Amazing. Worked just great. I've learned much from that - Both the logic and usage of the newer syntax with these functions.